# Why array swallows more elements than its capacity?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm newbie to C. And studying about Array.
tutor says the number in the bracket defines the memory size allowed to the array.

for example, if I define array like

```
int luckyNumbers[10]
```

this array can't swallow more than 10 elements.
However, it swallows more than 10, although it still says its size as 10.

here's what i've done

```
int main()
{
    int luckyNumbers[10];
    size_t n = sizeof(luckyNumbers)/sizeof(int);
    printf("%d\n", n);  // "10"

    luckyNumbers[1] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[2] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[3] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[4] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[5] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[6] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[7] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[8] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[9] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[10] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[11] = 80;
    luckyNumbers[12] = 90;

    printf("%d\n", luckyNumbers[12]); // "90". working right
    size_t n2 = sizeof(luckyNumbers) / sizeof(int); 
    printf("%d", n2);                     //still "10". why not 12?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` tells you how big the array is, not how much you've stored in it.  Also C doesn't check for array overflow.

Comment: You've just discovered what all the fuss is about [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) in C.  Your program might appear to still work.

Comment: In short, this is *undefined behavior*. It might seem to work, it might crash, it might reformat your hard disk, it might create a space-time rift and devour our solar system.

Comment: "`n2` is still `10`". In C you can't expand an array by writing beyond its bounds.

Comment: The array hasn't grown to accommodate the new elements, you've just written past the end of the array and clobbered any objects in memory after it.  C doesn't require the implementation to do any bounds checking on array accesses.  As long as you don't overwrite anything "important" your code will appear to function normally.  You declared the array to be 10 elements wide, and that's what `sizeof` is reporting.